# How to efficiently check if two columns in the same table is one-to-one mapping?

Tags: sql-server

Even though the distinct value counts equals, it did not necessarily mean an one-to-one mapping relation.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Column_A]) FROM MyTable 
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT [Column_B]) FROM MyTable
```

Column A: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1
Column B: a b c d e f g h i j  j

The query above return a value of 10 for each column but they are not one-to-one mapping.

How can I exactly check the existence of this `matching type?`
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a distinct count. This `COUNT(DISTINCT [Column_A])` is a distinct count. Both queries above will just count the number of records in your table, not the unique values.

Comment: What do you mean. matching type?

Comment: @reds One-to-one mapping

Comment: Please provide some detailed examples, tables with some test data and expected outcome. Currently your question is very unclear.

Comment: this is impossible to one on one mapping coz your data is already a count,  your query return all numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume all values are not `NULL`. The query result shows the value violates 1 to 1 relation.

```
-- Check Column A value which DOES NOT maps to exactly 1 Column_B value
SELECT Column_A, COUNT(Column_B) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column_A HAVING COUNT(Column_B) > 1

-- Check Column B value which DOES NOT maps to exactly 1 Column_A value
SELECT Column_B, COUNT(Column_A) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column_B HAVING COUNT(Column_A) > 1
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect for the question that was asked, this will flag any value that appears more than once in either column even if that value has a one-to-one pairing with the other column.

Answer (score 5):

The top and accepted answers are both incorrect! I came here looking for a way to do this in a single query, but I'm not sure that exists. Failing that, I think this is the simplest answer which will check if it is a one-to-one relationship (the answer doesn't ask for any info on the non-one-to-one values, just whether the columns are one-to-one):

```
SELECT [Column_A] FROM MyTable GROUP BY [Column_A] HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Column_B]) > 1
SELECT [Column_B] FROM MyTable GROUP BY [Column_B] HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Column_A]) > 1
```

If both of those queries return zero rows, you know each value of `Column_A` maps to only one value of `Column_B` and each value of `Column_B` maps to one value of `Column_A`, so they are definitionally one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

This query will show you any values for [Column_A] which have multiple values for [Column_B]. If it returns no rows, you have a 1 to 1 relationship.

```
select [Column_A], count([Column_B]) as not_distinct
from (select [Column_A], [Column_B] from MyTable
      group by [Column_A], [Column_B]) subtable
group by [Column_A]
having count([Column_B]) >1;
```

Comment: This just proves it's a many-to-one relationship! You can consider a table with two rows and two columns, where the first column has values ['A', 'B'] and the second column has values ['C', 'C'], to see why. This query would give that 'A' and 'B' each have one distinct value in the second column, and so would return no rows, but it's obviously not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

You can test one-to-one relationship with Group By.

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B

SELECT Column_A FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column_A

SELECT Column_B FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column_B
```

The result count should be same for above three queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) `+` [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ColA ,ColB ORDER BY ID ) RN
     FROM TableName
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

If count return some value means they **are not 1:1 Mapping** other wise both columns have unique pair

Answer (score 0):

I used this query according to the definition of one-to-one mapping.

```
WITH FREQ AS (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  [Column_B]) AS Freq  FROM MyTable GROUP BY 
[Column_A])
SELECT DISTINCT Freq  FROM FREQ 
ORDER BY Freq DESC

WITH FREQ AS (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  [Column_A]) AS Freq  FROM MyTable GROUP BY 
[Column_B])
SELECT DISTINCT Freq  FROM FREQ 
ORDER BY Freq DESC
```

Many thanks, all genius for your excellent ideas.

Comment: So, in your solution, you are looking for the only value of FREQ.Freq to be 1 in both cases, right?