# Check one-to-one relationship between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns which I suspect have redundant information - imagine abbreviation and full name, where abbreviation and full name likely have a one-to-one relationship. I want to figure out whether there is a one-to-one relationship, and identify any places where it doesn't check out.

I am working with SQL Server, if that helps.

I've taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150208/how-to-efficiently-check-if-two-columns-in-the-same-table-is-one-to-one-mapping). 
However, it's not quite what I need, since if I have two copies of the same pair, then it will flag.

What I want to do is more similar to [this question in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687204/check-one-on-one-relationship-between-two-columns). It looks like the functionality is all available in SQL, but since there's also other context columns, I'd like to have the ability to view where the relationship doesn't hold (they could just be data errors).

E.g. this table is good:

```
col1 | col2 | context
1 | a | cont1
2 | b | cont2
3 | c | cont3
1 | a | cont4
3 | c | cont5
```

because every 1 in col1 matches with an 'a' and nothing else, every 2 matches with 'b', etc. And every 'a' matches with only '1', etc.

This table is not good:

```
col1 | col2 | context
1 | a | cont1
2 | b | cont2
3 | c | cont3
1 | b | cont4
3 | c | cont5
```

since 1 matches with both 'a' and 'b'. In this case, I'd like to have some way of indicating that the 1st, 2nd, and 4th rows are problematic and should receive manual review.

For now, I'm assuming that there aren't any NULLS (I plan to deal with those separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the bad rows using aggregation.  If I understand correctly:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having max(col2) <> min(col2);
```

If you want the original rows, use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```